# Django: redirecting to an external URL stored in the dB

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm building a Django application.  My end goal is for the user to be able to click a link to be redirected to an external site.  Here's my code:

**models.py**

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    source_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def purchase(request, entry_id):
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, pk=entry_id)
    return redirect(entry.source_url)
```

**entry.html**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'purchase' %}">Purchase!</a>
{% endif %}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('entries/<int:entry_id>', views.entry, name='entry'),
]
```

The data in the database looks as follows:

```
id    manufacturer     source_url
1     Mercedes         https://www.mbusa.com/en/home
2     BMW              https://www.bmw.com/en/index.html
3     Audi             https://www.audiusa.com/us/web/en.html
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'purchase' not found. 'purchase' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

As a test, I changed the following line of code:

From:  `<a href="{% url 'purchase' %}">Go to Source!</a>`

To:  `<a href="www.google.com">Go to Source!</a>`

This eliminated the "reverse" error, but the URL that it created was:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/entries/www.google.com
```

Is the "reverse" error caused by the lack of a URL route for "purchase" in `urls.py`?  If yes, how would I define this?

Thanks in advance for helping this Django newbie!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For redirect from view you can do:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
def purchase(request, entry_id):
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, pk=entry_id)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(entry.source_url)
```

and you can solve `<a href="www.google.com">Go to Source!</a>` problem by:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Go to Source!</a>
```

entry.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'purchase' entry_id %}">Purchase!</a>
{% endif %}
```

here `entry_id` will be the primary key of your Entry Table.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('entries/<int:entry_id>', views.entry, name='entry'),
    path('purchase/<int:entry_id>', views.purchase, name='purchase'),
]
```

Comment: Jafoor -- thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I'm seeing the same error message: `Reverse for 'purchase' not found. 'purchase' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: @equanimity have you checked it out that your `source_url ` contains `http` or `https` at the beginning? It's working on me for the above solution.

Comment: The `source_url` field values contain `https`.  For example:  `https://unagiscooters.com/products/the-scooter/`

Comment: haven't you create any `url` for `purchase ` function?

Comment: Do you mean that I need to create a `url` for the `purchase()` function in the `urls.py` file?

Comment: @equanimity yes! i am editing my answer do like that.